# No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type - StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a Web API project in which I'm using 3 generic interfaces for my constructor implementation.  My IoC container is StructureMap.  Here are the following interfaces:

```
public interface IStatisticsBase<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ExecStatisticsBase_SP(string x, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? xType);
}

public interface IStatisticsExtend<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ExecStatisticsExtend_SP(string x, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? xType, int? dx, decimal? levelFrom, decimal? levelTo);
}   

public interface IStatisticsBaseAndExtend<T>:IStatisticsBase<T>, IStatisticsExtend<T>
{
}
```

My default registry is as follows:

```
Scan(scan =>
{
    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    scan.AssemblyContainingType<IStatisticsBase<T>>();
    scan.AddAllTypesOf<IStatisticsBase<T>>();

    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    scan.AssemblyContainingType<IStatisticsExtend<T>>();
    scan.AddAllTypesOf<IStatisticsExtend<T>>();

    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    scan.AssemblyContainingType<IStatisticsBaseAndExtend<T>>();
    scan.AddAllTypesOf<IStatisticsBaseAndExtend<T>>();
});
```

And the error occurs here in the StructureMapDependencyScope.cs file:

```
protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key) 
{
    IContainer container = (CurrentNestedContainer ?? Container);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) 
    {
        return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface
            ? container.TryGetInstance(serviceType)
            : container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    return container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
}
```

With the error message:

No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IStatisticsBaseAndExtend'\r\n\r\nThere is no configuration specified for IStatisticsBaseAndExtend

Is suspect I need to register my interfaces is as follows:

```
For<IStatisticsBase<T>>().....
For<IStatisticsExtend<T>()....
For<IStatisticsBaseAndExtend<T>>...
```

but am not sure what the syntax is.

Thanks

Comment: where does the implementing class(es) live?

Comment: All StructureMap code is in the same project as my Web API controllers.  My interfaces are in a separate project that contains my entity framework code and repositories.  I have been able to register other interfaces/repositories using the following syntax:      For<IPopulationStatistics<PopulationState_SelectByDateStatisticsFormat_Result>>().Use<PopulationStatisticsRepoDate>();

Comment: For open generic type the registration should something like c.For(typeof(IStatisticsBase<>)).Use(typeof(SomeImplementation<>))

Answer (score 0):

When you use **StructureMap**, you can make a class like the following codes to define a **default class** for an **interface** :

```
public class TheRegistery :StructureMap.Registry
{
    public TheRegistery()
    {
        For<IMyInterface>().Use<YourClassName>();  // << This Syntax

        Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
            scanner.AssemblyContainingType<UserMailer>();
        });
    }
}
```